# How to achieve Android and HBase Connection?

Tags: java, android, database, apache, hbase

I'm running Hbase 0.94.0 pseudo distributed mode. I have few million records in them. Now i've created an android app, which needs to communicate with hbase, where i need to retrieve data from HBase and after manipulation i need to put it back in Hbase.

I've seacrhed over the internet. I couldn't find anything useful.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create a web-based API in a language that HBase can communicate with, and have Android interact with this web API? This setup also helps with security, so you don't have random Android clients accessing your HBase directly.

Comment: @Suresh_Hadoop: Did you achieve the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the REST API for HBase (Stargate)

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate